# Create Multiple Endpoints for Bot Service in single domain. [Create a new folder with existing code as subdomain]

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, botframework

I am using Bot Framework v4, which is based on ASP.Net core.
I need to create a new endpoint for each user who signup on my site. On a single domain, I can host only a single site. So I am thinking to create a new folder/subdomain and add existing BFv4 code within that.

For e.g., If user signup with MyUserName then it will create a new folder/subdomain dynamically such that It is accessible via
`https://MyUserName.MyWebSite.com/api/messages` or `https://MyWebSite.com/MyUserName/api/messages`.

Here `appsetting.json` and `app.bot` files will have different content for each signed up a user that's why I am thinking to create a new copy of the file instead of obtaining username from URL.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you need a different bot file and app settings file for each user?  There may be a better solution other than this from adesign perspective.

Comment: @JasonSowers `appsettings.json` file contains configuration details for Bot such as Luis App Id, Pass, Microsoft App Id, Pass, etc. and `bot` file is created by bot framework itself in BFv4 for managing bot. This file also contains appId, password, and  endPoint URL. For each of Bot I have different details so I need different files for each of bots.

Comment: @NilMehta Are you going to create new bot for each user who is signing up to your site?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh Yes, my client requirement is something like this. Now I am move ahead with own custom framework for that.